# var vs. let inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

The following piece of code will produce *1, 2, 3, 4*

```
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4];

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(array[i]);
  }, 1000);
}
```

Whereas using var i = 0 in the for loop will produce *undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined*

```
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(array[i]);
  }, 1000);
}
```

I understand var and let have different scopes but can somebody explain why in the *var* example, *i* evaluates to 4 in each iteration?

Comment: Because the loop has finished and `i` has been incremented to 4, before the first `setTimeout()` callback has been invoked.

Comment: Because by the time the function specified in your `setTimeout ` runs, the loop has finished and `i = 4`.